# Is this polynomial correct?

Tags: python, polynomial, pandas

Disclaimer: I have no knowledge of stats.

I fitted a polynomial to data points. I expected it to look like an exponential decreasing curve, but this seems to dip below zero, as well as the histogram seems to have a gap between 4 and 5.

1) Am I doing something wrong in calculating the poly?

2) Is the graph just a bug in pandas or can I fix it with parameters?

[image]

Comment: If you assume it to be exponential, why wouldn't you use exponential function rather then polynomial..? As you can see, your data seems to decrease and then stays at zero, while polynomial function you fitted is U-shaped so it does not describe the data accordingly.

Comment: @Tim thanks for helping, I don't see how I fitted it to be u-shaped, looking at the data it seems to just decrease.

Comment: This is how polynomials work.